# Sketch (draw, trace) image at 45º angles

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, drawing, cartography

Hard to explain. But: I am in the process of creating a stylized map of a small country in the North-West of Europe ;-)

So, basically, I want to create the picture on the right from the picture on the left:

[image]

Now, I've done this before and it can be done using Illustrators Pen tool, clicking point after point using SHIFT to force 45º angles.

But I wonder:

**Can this be automated?** Jazzy vector *in*, straight vector *out*

or,

**Is there any program offering any tool that allows me to do this while using a continuous drawing tool** like Illustrators 'pencil' tool?

And, any help in re-formulating this question is also much appreciated :)

**EDIT** Thanks all for your elaborate answers! I can tell you spend quite some time in composing. But I notice I did not phrase my question question clearly enough. Yes, I can use the pen-tool-with-shift in AI or a grid, in Inkscape. But what I would like to is to draw freely (no pun intended)  — as if holding a pencil — while my hand is being restrained to only draw at 45º angles (0º, 45º, 90º, 135º … 315º). Metaphorically, of course.

Comment: I can recommend a very useful Illustrator Plugin called VectorScribe. https://astutegraphics.com/software/vectorscribe/ It offers tools to set fixed angles for drawing (Protractor) and to round edges (Dynamic Corners).  EDIT: Protractor seems to have been removed from VS, but is now part of the free DirectPrefs https://astutegraphics.com/software/directprefs/

Comment: Very interesting plugin. Really powerful indeed.

Comment: Instead of using a pen tool use line tool

Comment: Also its possible to make the os make shift or any other key sticky.

Answer (score 1):

In Inkscape, you can define a grid with 45° (document setting), make the image partly transparent, enable snap to grid and thereby help yourself by manually performing the task, drawing over the shape to the nearest next grid point close to the shape:

[image]

I'm not aware of an Inkscape tool, being more into the automation of the task. Screenshot from german interface, I guess the location of the settings in the dialog is identical.

Comment: +1 for Inkscape and the 45º Grid. And indeed finding Zeeland ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the `Constrain Angle` in the **Preferences > General** to change the default angle artwork is created at.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the trouble creating a little screencast!   I'm afraid this doesn't help me. The setting you show doesn't affect the pencil tool. And it prevents the pen tool from drawing at 0º and 90º

Comment: If you just want pen tool paths to be at 45° you can hold down the `Shift` key when creating them. You can set the "shift angles" in `Preferences > Smart Guides` Then turn on Smart Guides in the View menu. And the Pencil tool is specifically *designed* to ignore all many snapping, guide, constrain, and grid settings in many instances to be "freeform" overall.

Comment: Indeed, the pen-tool-with-shift works . Apparently, what I want simply does not exist or I am not able to explain it clearly enough.

Comment: +1 for using Smart Guides. You might only need the Construction Guides active (s. Preferences), otherwise there's too much other snapping taking place.